# I am trying to add google signin in my app but this dependency does not working

Tags: java, android

```
app/build.gradle    
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.
<a href="openFile:D:/DeVEloPER/Android/InternshipProjects/Watchman/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.">Show Details</a>    
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.
<a href="openFile:D:/DeVEloPER/Android/InternshipProjects/Watchman/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.">Show Details</a> 
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.
<a href="openFile:D:/DeVEloPER/Android/InternshipProjects/Watchman/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.">Show Details</a>    
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.
<a href="openFile:D:/DeVEloPER/Android/InternshipProjects/Watchman/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@release/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.">Show Details</a>  
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.
<a href="openFile:D:/DeVEloPER/Android/InternshipProjects/Watchman/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1.">Show Details</a>
```

Comment: Can you show your project's top-level `build.gradle` and your app-level `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

update your project gradle file with the latest version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

also place

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at bottom of your app gradle dependencies .